# CSS image overlay not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, overlay

This is driving me crazy. On mobile, when you tap the portfolio images, the overlay of text would appear. It was definitely working before but then I've been adding more to my html and css and now it doesn't work. I tried reverting to an old commit, playing around with the css, but I just can't figure out what caused it to stop working.

Here is my html code and css:

```
    <div class="projects">
      <a name="projects"></a>
      <div class="hold-it">
        <img src="Stranger_places.jpg" alt="Stranger Places" />
        <span class="overlay"><h4>Stranger Places&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</h4><p>Conceived due to my love for traversing wild and exotic landscapes. It is a Web App for travelers looking to get off the beaten path. Made with HTML5, Ruby, JS, and Bootstrap on a Rails framework.</p><a href="https://github.com/jcotzin/Stranger_Places" target="_blank" title="Github"><i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true">&emsp;</i></a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="hold-it">
        <img src="coding_resources.png" />
        <span class="overlay"><h4>codeXhunter&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4><p>A Web App for discovering and sharing Web Developers' favorite coding resources. Made with HTML5, Ruby, JS and Materialize on a Rails framework.</p><a href="https://github.com/jcotzin/Coding_Resources" target="_blank" title="Github"><i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true">&emsp;</i></a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="hold-it">
        <img src="shouni.png" />
        <span class="overlay"><h4>Shouni</h4><p>Shouni is an anime generator app for fellow anime-lovers. Never get bored on those lonely nights! Shouni was made with HTML5, jQuery and Ruby on a Rails framework. </p>
<a href="https://github.com/JAnderson88/shouni" target="_blank" title="Github"><i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a><a href="https://stormy-badlands-22918.herokuapp.com/" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>


  * {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .projects {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 40px auto auto auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
  }

  .hold-it {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 265px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }

  .overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in;
  }

  .hold-it:hover .overlay {
    opacity: .75;
  }

  .hold-it p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    font: 100 18px "Helvetica Neue";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

  .hold-it h4 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    margin: auto;
    font: 100 24px "Helvetica Neue";
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

  .hold-it img {
    height: 300px;
    width:335px
  }
```

Comment: here's a fiddle of it... https://jsfiddle.net/L5bsorxu/
see: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/click-function-for-hover-states-on-touch-devices/ suggests using focus instead of hover for mobile?